# No route matches [GET] "/logout"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, httprequest, store

In my session controller I have a method called destroy who is pointed in the route as "Logout", the function of it is only reset the session variable to nil and redirect to the store index:

```
def destroy
session[:user_id] = nil
redirect_to store_url, notice: "Logged out"
end
```

In the route file I declared the pointer:

```
get "sessions/destroy"

controller :sessions do
get  'login' => :new
post 'login' => :create
delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```

Now in the browser I should trigger the HTTP DELETE VERB, but instead it takes the GET and the route can't be found it.

For example:

localhost:3000/logout, the error is   **No route matches [GET] "/logout"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you should put explicit method: :destroy, like this:

```
= link_to 'Destroy', session, method: :destroy
```

Comment: but right know i'm not using any button, I'm writing it directly in the url as the example: localhost:3000/logout

Comment: When you type that into your browser, the browser will always assume you are using HTTP GET request. You should use `get 'logout' => :destroy` in your routes to get that working.

Comment: The standard request by the URL is GET... You should put another if you wanna change.

Comment: Done, change the verb Delete by the Get, simple errors can make things impossible, thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

If you look into your Devise initializer in `config/initializers/devise.rb` and seek through line 236 and switch to `:get` if you want your users to sign out via a GET request.

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: my project doesn't have the devise.rb file at least not in that folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error..

this worked for me.

Just changed the routes from..

```
delete  'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
#to
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```